# Поиск значения по всем столбцам таблицы в MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Как организовать поиск значения по всем столбцам таблицы?

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from table where concat(col1,col2,col3) like '%search_string%'
```

Без явного указания столбцов потребуется динамический SQL.

Answer (score 6):

```
select * from `table` where `col1` like "%$query_string%" or `col2` like "%$query_string%" or `col3` like "%$query_string%"...
```

Так ищет PHPMyAdmin.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`;
```

Для определения колонок. =)

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт поиска по всем полям таблицы на вхождение хотя бы одного слова из запроса

```
$search = trim(substr($search, 0, 64)); // Это можно убрать, это ограничение на 64 символа в поиске
    $search = preg_replace("#\#s=#msi", "", $search);
    $search = preg_replace("/[^\w\x7F-\xFF\s]/", " ", $search);
    $search = preg_replace("#  +#msi", " ", $search);
    if(empty($search))
        return false;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field1` LIKE '%".preg_replace("# #msi", "%' OR `field1` LIKE '%", $search)."%' OR `field2` LIKE '%".preg_replace("# #msi", "%' OR `field2` LIKE '%", $search)."%'");
```

Comment: Боже, что это?... О_О  
Нет, мне нравится, но что это?... У меня аж глаза разбежались

Comment: Это код на php, который получает строку запроса `$search`. Потом убирает пробелы в конце и начале строки. Потом убирает спецсимволы, потом убирает лишние пробелы (в итоге получается строка, которую можно смело совать в базу), и потом производит поиск по базе.

В результате - находятся все результаты, в которых есть вхождение хотя бы одного слова по запросу)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но нужно чтобы поиск проходил по всем столбцам, явного указания имен столбцов.чтобы можно было применить к любой таблице

Comment: Не уверен, что это возможно средствами только MySQL.
Можно написать функцию на php, которая первым запросом будет получать список всех полей. А вторым уже проводить поиск.

Comment: так и сделал..но хотелось всё одним запросом сделать..

Answer (score 0):

Процедура для поиска значений во всех столбцах таблицы.

Проверено на Postgres.

Смысл таков: выбираем все столбцы таблицы из схемы. Потом обходим выбранные значения в 'цикле' и собираем запрос, который выбирает количество совпадений с искомым значением больше нуля.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `findValue`(
    IN `_value` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `_table` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `_database` VARCHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Search the value in any columns of table.'
BEGIN

DECLARE done BOOL;
DECLARE t, c varchar(250);
DECLARE _query LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = _database AND table_name = _table;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = true;

Open cur;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO t, c;

    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

        IF _query <> '' THEN
            SET _query = concat(_query, ' UNION ');
        END IF;

        SET _query = concat(_query, 'SELECT "', t, '" as tbl, "', c, '" as col, count(', c, ') as have from ', concat(_database, '.', t), ' WHERE ', c, ' like "%', _value, '%" HAVING have > 0');


END LOOP;
Close cur; 

SET @q = _query;
prepare qqq from @q;
execute qqq;
END
```

вызов: call findValue('value', 'table_namer', 'database');