# Поиск по таблице MySQL точных совпадений без указания столбцов

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Подскажите php запрос, который будет искать в таблице точное совпадение без указания столбцов или в нескольких столбцах. 
Например нужно найти "1234" в таблице test
В этой таблице есть 5 столбцов (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) и в одном из них может быть это значение.

Вот мне и нужно взять запись из таблицы но при этом я не знаю в каком столбце находится нужное значение..

Или второй вариант - когда я знаю, что значение нужно искать в столбцах 2, 3 или 5.

Причем если это значение есть в одном столбце - в другом его не может быть.

Кто подскажет?=)

Comment: `SELECT * from test_table WHERE row1=1234 OR row2=1234 OR row3=1234 OR row4=1234 OR row5=1234`


Но, сдаётся мне, при такой постановке задачи лечить нужно что-то в другом месте.

Comment: >php запрос

Это называется sql запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуйтесь поиском тут уже отвечали: [Поиск значения по всем столбцам таблицы в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37063/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

К примеру есть такая таблица "search"

```
 Key    |    a    |    b    |    c    |    d    
 cats       901      1234       3578     7819
 dog        781      561        321      889
 bird       1234     3434       019      1114
```

Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
$value='1234';
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * from search WHERE (a= '".$value."' OR b= '".$value."' OR c= '".$value."' OR d= '".$value."') ");
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['key'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where '1234' in(f2,f3,f5)
```