# Laravel|Eloquent. Поиск во всей таблице

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, orm, eloquent

Использую ORM Eloquent отдельно от Laravel, возникла необходимость поиска по базе данных MySQL через оператор `LIKE`, возник вопрос - как искать по всем полям определенной таблицы? То есть, не указывать collum `->where('collum', 'like', '%' . $text . '$');`, а производить поиск по всей таблице, какие есть способы реализовать подобный поиск?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск значения по всем столбцам таблицы в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37063/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-mysql)

Comment: Да, вопросы схожи, но там реализация через чистый SQL, а мне нужна реализация через Eloquent.
На данный момент реализовал следующим образом, имеется массив формата: collum => текст для поиска, после циклом обращаюсь к ORM, сохраняю ответы в нужный массив и привожу его в одномерный массив. Немного костыльно, но работает. Если не найду лучшего решения, то прикреплю как ответ.